# How to trace a process sending data over network?

Tags: mobile-data

I found that some mobile data is consumed by unknown process. There's a huge difference between my ISP report and glasswire report, around 40mb for each 100mb used.

I know my phone is infected and someone spying on me but couldn't find how to get rid of that.

I wiped boot/recovery/data/cache and dalvik partitions before installing a custom ROM (dotOS) from a trusted computer. I managed to root the phone and install a firewall to check what's happening but got nothing worth it.

My assumption is that some process is still running somewhere, I have no idea how can I, at least, see what's going on. I do not have any background with Android development but I understand most of the concepts around it.

It's not a system application so please do not mention that.

Comment: Afwall can only see user / system apps! That doesn't solve my problems.

Comment: Check your mobile data plan regarding the charge unit size - if it is large (e.g. 100KB) you loose a lot of mb just because your MNO is always rounding up to 100KB when the network coverage is interrupted even if only a few bytes were effectively transferred.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to sniff outgoing network traffic. Since Android uses Linux kernel, we can make use of in-kernel reliable firewall: `netfilter` which is controlled using userspace utility `iptables`. It's the easiest available option for rooted phones.
Through a root commandline:

```
# iptables -I OUTOUT -j LOG --log-prefix "SNIFFER " --log-uid --log-level 7
```

This will log all outgoing traffic to kernel log that you can capture and save to text file:

```
# dmesg -w | grep SNIFFER
```

This will provide you `uid` of the all the processes sending out traffic, which can be used to trace the processes.

`AFWall+` app also makes use of iptables `owner` module to block traffic from certain user/system apps (UIDs) including root.

For further details on capturing packets, see [View network traffic requested by app](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/204022/218526).